# Origin instantly crashes with PlayOnLinux

Tags: games, playonlinux

After installing origin (OriginSetup.exe) using PlayOnLinux, I pressed play and almost instantaneously it says:

```
Error in Main
Origin crashed.
Click on debug link to get more details.
```

And in debug it says:

```
[03/28/15 12:26:31] - Running wine- Origin.exe (Working directory : /home/ben/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Windows/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Origin)
err:module:import_dll Loading library MSVCP100.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Origin\\Origin.exe") failed (error c000007b).
err:module:import_dll Loading library MSVCR100.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Origin\\Origin.exe") failed (error c000007b).
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Origin\\Origin.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Versions:

Ubuntu Version: 14.04

PlayOnLinux Version: 4.2.2

Origin Installer Version: 9.5.10 (downloaded [from here](http://filehippo.com/download_origin/tech/))

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by following some advice found on [this forum](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-12414-EA_Origin_startup_fails_on_Arch_Linux.html). In case the link is broken, here is a synopsis of what I did:

1. Create a new virtual drive as 32 bit windows XP
2. Install the following libraries with PlayOnLinux: dx9d36, mono28, msxml3, mfc42
3. Download dnsapi.dll and put it into windows/system32 in the virtual drive directory
4. Download OriginSetup.exe from somewhere (at the time it isn't availible from EA)
5. Select "install a program" in PlayOnLinux then install OriginSetup.exe, make sure to overwrite into the virtual drive that you just made
6. Enjoy EA games on linux! (as long as they are compatible with WINE)

Answer (score 0):

The winehq appdb says that `OriginThinSetup.exe` won't work.
(https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26175)

The playonlinux installation script for Origin has a download link for `OriginSetup.exe`. Unfortunately the download link is broken.
(https://www.playonlinux.com/en/changelog-1059-EAs_Origin.html)

It looks like your only option might be to track down an old version of `OriginSetup.exe`

Comment: I tried downloading `OriginSetup.exe` from a slightly suspicious website ([file hippo link](http://filehippo.com/download_origin/tech/)), and I get the same error

Comment: In your terminal output, there are lines saying you're missing MSVCP100.dll. Start `winecfg` in a terminal and add dll overrides (native,builtin) for `msvcp100` and `msvcr100`. Or type `winetricks vcrun2010` to have the Visual C++ 2010 libraries installed and these overrides added automatically. Note that the winetricks command fails on some 64-bit installations.

Comment: I added the overrides and did `winetricks vcrun2010`, and I still get the same error.

Comment: I tried using 32 bit windows, and that boots and tries to update, but after updating it says there was an error and I should reinstall, using the broken download link.

Answer (score 0):

i just installed the Origin launcher with lutris and am installing a couple of games now ;
just download **lutris** from their website,
and run / start the plus (+) in the left top to
add a game. then select the **OriginSetup.exe** file
to start installing the client.
i did not try the legacy installer **OriginThinSetup.exe** though, but this is working instead of playonlinux - which i ve also tried - it is crashing during install.
as you can see on their website the Origin Launcher is working just fine :
https://lutris.net/games/origin/